# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' main.js yii2

Tags: yii2

The front page of my web application in yii2 is messed up. I'm not quite sure why. It runs perfectly fine in localhost. When I move it to the server it shows different. The Footer has gone up, the jumbotrons are not centered etc.
It's like below - 
[image]

There's one error in the console - `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'`

Upon clicking on main.js I get below -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="_csrf">
    <title>G.M.Pharmaceuticals</title>
    <link href="/assets/4ec4bebd/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <nav id="w0" class="navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top navbar"><div class="container"><div class="navbar-header"><button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#w0-collapse"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span></button><a class="navbar-brand" href="/index.php">GM Pharmaceuticals</a></div><div id="w0-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse"><ul id="w1" class="navbar-nav navbar-right nav"><li class="active"><a href="/index.php?r=site%2Findex">Home</a></li>
<li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu <span class="caret"></span></a><ul id="w2" class="dropdown-menu"></ul></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?r=site%2Fsignup">Signup</a></li>
<li><a href="/index.php?r=site%2Flogin">Login</a></li></ul></div></div></nav>    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="breadcrumb"><li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="active">G.M.Pharmaceuticals</li>
<li class="active">G.M.Pharmaceuticals</li>
</ul>
                <div class="site-index">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Welcome to G.M.Pharmaceuticals</h1>
    <p class="lead">Please contact the system Administrator for credentials</p>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="pull-left">&copy; GM Pharmaceuticals 2018</p>

        <p class="pull-right">Powered by <a href="http://www.yiiframework.com/" rel="external">Yii Framework</a></p>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="/assets/7821041f/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/87474ea6/yii.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/4ec4bebd/js/bootstrap.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

I've compared /site/index.php and /web/layout/main.php with my other projects but didn't find any issue.

I also tried composer update, but that also didn't help. Tried removing the vendor directory and composer install bu that didn't help either.

In other pages also I have this layout error -

[image]

You can see here - where the footer is and what happened to the datepicker.

/frontend/js/main.js file looks like -

```
$(function(){
    $('#modalButton').click(function(){
        $('#modal').modal('show')
        .find('#modalContent')
        .load($(this).attr('value'));
    });

});
```

/site/view/index.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

$this->title = 'G.M.Pharmaceuticals';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
//$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-index">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Welcome to G.M.Pharmaceuticals</h1>
    <p class="lead">Please contact the system Administrator for credentials</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

/layout/main.php

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use frontend\assets\AppAsset;
use common\widgets\Alert;
use kartik\sidenav\SideNav;
use yii\helpers\Url;

AppAsset::register($this);
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>

</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <?php

    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => 'GM Pharmaceuticals',
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
        ],
    ]);
    $menuItems = [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        .......


        // ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
        // ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
    ];
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/site/signup']];
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
    } else {
        $menuItems[] = [
            'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
            'url' => ['/site/logout'],
            'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
        ];
    }
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
        'items' => $menuItems,
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
    ?>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ]) ?>

        <?= Alert::widget() ?>
        <?= $content ?>        
    </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="pull-left">&copy; GM Pharmaceuticals <?= date('Y') ?></p>

        <p class="pull-right"><?= Yii::powered() ?></p>
    </div>
</footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

/frontend/asset/AppAsset

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://www.yiiframework.com/
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2008 Yii Software LLC
 * @license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/
 */

namespace frontend\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/main.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

SiteController Action Index

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }
```

Comment: You have error in your JS code in `main.js`, please attach some of the content of this file.

Comment: Updated main.js file in question

Comment: It's the only code in your JS file? No `script` tags? Do you use any other assets in your controller? The html you provided is from the code or from view page source?

Comment: On the error message upon clicking on the main.js link, I get the HTML in the question. It comes from combining /layout/main.php and /site/view/index.php

Comment: Can you please attach the view file and the layout?

Comment: Both updated in the question

Comment: Are you sure this file (`main.js`) exists on the server? Do you use some rewrite rules to hide `frontend` from URLs?

Comment: I do have a .htaccess file with some rewrite rule. But I don't see it in my app folder right now. May be it's hidden somehow.

Comment: Please attach content of: `frontend\assets\AppAsset.php`. Also, in your controller you have any beforeAction? You render the page content with regular `render` method?

Comment: Both Updated in the question.

Comment: I think your main.js file is in the wrong location, try to put it in frontend\web\js

Comment: It is there only.

Comment: Check in developer tools under network tabs if it can't fetch one of the assets (maybe one of the js files) and what is the reason (error code, and response)?